# Get records for a list of multiple entities on Wikidata

Tags: python, sparql, pseudocode, records, wikidata

I am mapping multiple entities (Q entries) in Wikidata for which I need the same record of properties (P entries). For sake of this question, say I have a list of five Wikidata entities (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5) for which I want to retrieve the same property records (say, P1, P2, and P3). I know all Q and P in advance.

I understand how to pose a SPARQL query for an individual record (say for Q1), and I also understand how to specify the return of labels using the special SERVICE wikibase:label function for P1, P2, and P3.

First question, is there a way to loop over a list of entities (Q1 to Q5) with a given SPARQL query using only SPARQL?

If the answer is No, does any example Python or pseudocode exist for issuing single SPARQL queries looping over a list of external identifiers (Q1 to Q5), say provided as an external text or CSV file?

If there is a simple way to approach this, I'd love to hear.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11261/wikidata-extract

Comment: Thank you, also very helpful. I did not know about 
TABernacle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you’re looking for the `VALUES` clause:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?class ?classLabel ?projectLabel WHERE {
  VALUES ?item { wd:Q1 wd:Q2 wd:Q3 wd:Q4 wd:Q5 }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?class;
        wdt:P5008 ?project.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fclass%20%3FclassLabel%20%3FprojectLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%20wd%3AQ1%20wd%3AQ2%20wd%3AQ3%20wd%3AQ4%20wd%3AQ5%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fclass%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP5008%20%3Fproject.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Lucas, fantastic! Thank you. This is exactly what I was seeking. Is there a known limit to the VALUES clause (either in SPARQL or the Wikidata endpoint?).

Comment: Eventually the query will become too long for a `GET` request and you’ll have to use `POST` instead, but beyond that I’m not aware of any hard limit. (But, like, you probably can’t use this for *millions* of items ;) )

Comment: Again, Lucas, thanks. I will look into other Wikidata documentation about best practices for how to hammer their site.